# Determine elapsed number of months & days between two dates

Tags: vba

I am trying to determine the number of months and remaining days between two dates.

Test dates:
04/19/1995
12/26/22

The answer per https://www.calculator.net/date-calculator.html: 332 months 7 days

The answer generated per my VBA code: 332 months 3 days.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

    ' Calculate the difference between two dates in months and remaining days

    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim months As Long
    Dim days As Long

    startDate = Application.InputBox("Enter a date:", "Date Input 1", Date, Type:=2)
    endDate = Application.InputBox("Enter another date:", "Date Input 2", Date, Type:=2)

    months = Abs(DateDiff("m", startDate, endDate))
    days = Abs(DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate)) Mod 30

    MsgBox "The difference between the two dates is: " & months & " months and " & days & " days."

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you included leap years?

Comment: Use `Dim MonthDate As Date: Months = DateDiff("m", StartDate, EndDate): MonthDate = DateAdd("m", Months, StartDate): Days = DateDiff("d", MonthDate, EndDate)`. Now use some If logic to deal with *the Start date greater than the End date* issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Date Difference in Months and Days

**The Button Code**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    DateDifference
End Sub
```

**The Main Method**

```vb
Sub DateDifference()
    ' Calculates the difference between two dates in months and days.
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Date Difference"
    Dim Prompts(): Prompts = VBA.Array("Enter a date:", "Enter another date:")
    Dim Titles(): Titles = VBA.Array("Date Input 1", "Date Input 2")
    
    ' Get the input using the 'GetInputDate' function.
    
    Dim InputValue As Variant
    Dim Dates(0 To 1) As Date
    
    Dim d As Long
    
    For d = 0 To 1
        InputValue = GetInputDate(Prompts(d), Titles(d))
        If IsEmpty(InputValue) Then Exit Sub
        Dates(d) = CDate(InputValue)
    Next d
   
    ' Determine the Start and End date ('Start <= End').

    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    
    If Dates(0) < Dates(1) Then
        StartDate = Dates(0)
        EndDate = Dates(1)
    Else
        StartDate = Dates(1)
        EndDate = Dates(0)
    End If

    ' Calculate the difference.

    Dim Months As Long: Months = DateDiff("m", StartDate, EndDate)
    Dim MonthDate As Date: MonthDate = DateAdd("m", Months, StartDate)
    Dim Days As Long: Days = DateDiff("d", MonthDate, EndDate)

    ' Inform.
    
    Dim Msg As String: Msg = "The difference between the two dates is " _
        & IIf(Months = 1, "one month", Months & " months") & " and " _
        & IIf(Days = 1, "one day", Days & " days") & "."
    MsgBox Msg, vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

**A Helper Function**

```vb
Function GetInputDate( _
    ByVal Prompt As String, _
    ByVal Title As String) _
As Variant ' a date or 'Empty'
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get Input Date"
    
    Dim InputValue As Variant, MsgAnswer As Long, Msg As String
    
    Do
        InputValue = Application.InputBox(Prompt, Title, Date, , , , , 2)
        If VarType(InputValue) = vbBoolean Then
            MsgBox "Canceled.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Function
        End If
        If IsDate(InputValue) Then GetInputDate = InputValue: Exit Function
        
        Msg = "The string """ & InputValue & """ can't be converted " _
            & "to a date. Do you want to try again?"
        MsgAnswer = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, PROC_TITLE)
        If MsgAnswer = vbNo Then Exit Function
    Loop

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The following line in your code -

```
days = Abs(DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate)) Mod 30
```

assumes that all months have 30 days. They do not!

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple because of the varying count of days of the months. You have to use `DateAdd` to obtain the correct month count.

This function does it right:

```vb
' Returns the difference in full months from DateOfBirth to current date,
' optionally to another date.
' Returns by reference the difference in days.
' Returns zero if AnotherDate is earlier than DateOfBirth.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap Months
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   any date/time value of data type Date
'
' DateAdd() is, when adding a count of months to dates of 31th (29th),
' used for check for month end as it correctly returns the 30th (28th)
' when the resulting month has 30 or less days.
'
' 2015-11-24. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function AgeMonthsDays( _
    ByVal DateOfBirth As Date, _
    Optional ByVal AnotherDate As Variant, _
    Optional ByRef Days As Integer) _
    As Long
    
    Dim ThisDate    As Date
    Dim Months      As Long
      
    If IsDateExt(AnotherDate) Then
        ThisDate = CDate(AnotherDate)
    Else
        ThisDate = Date
    End If
    
    ' Find difference in calendar Months.
    Months = DateDiff("m", DateOfBirth, ThisDate)
    If Months < 0 Then
        Months = 0
    Else
        If Months > 0 Then
            ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
            ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of DateOfBirth.
            If DateDiff("d", ThisDate, DateAdd("m", Months, DateOfBirth)) > 0 Then
                Months = Months - 1
            End If
        End If
        ' Find difference in days.
        Days = DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", Months, DateOfBirth), ThisDate)
    End If
        
    AgeMonthsDays = Months
  
End Function
```

Example (in the immidiate pane):

```vb
Days% = 0
? AgeMonthsDays(#04/19/1995#, #12/26/2022#, Days%), Days%
 332           7
```

It is from my library at **GitHub**: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).